# Dangers of calling ICLRRuntimeInfo.BindAsLegacyV2Runtime at runtime

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, runtime, app-config

I have a .NET application which uses Crystal Reports.  One of the big things that has held me back from upgrading to .NET 4.0 is that Crystal Reports won't work without the following lines in the app.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

The problem is that the app.config file contains all kinds of other configuration options, so it can't just be overwritten.  And making each client PC update manually is really out of the question.

And even if I do figure out how to update the file 100% accurately, I don't like having that stuff sitting in there permanently.  For example, if we wanted to go to .NET 5.0 some day, that would mean going through and deleting the version="v4.0" line from each config file.

I don't get why Microsoft would put this kind of configuration in the app.config file instead of a manifest file or something like that, that can be embedded directly in the executable.

Anyway, I finally found someone who had given an example of how to configure that setting at runtime instead of in a config file:

http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/

So what exactly are the dangers of setting the runtime property programmatically through ICLRRuntimeInfo.BindAsLegacyV2Runtime()?  Is there a chance of that the Guid on ICLRRuntimeInfo is going to change with some .NET service pack or something?

I have a hard time imagining what kind of problems this could cause problems down the road, and it's a lot easier to take it back out of the executable than try to update all the app.config files that already exist.  So what are the potential downsides?

Answer (score 0):

app.config is something that should be updated along with your executable and all other related content files. You can do it either way. There are some assemblies for which only the runtime method works.